# Android: Converting byte array into bitmap crashes

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin.android

The application crashes when I try to convert a large byte array to bitmap. The exception is `OutOfMemory`. I know what it means, but i'm wondering how does other applications on the same device work with large images? I think there should be a trick or something. The only solution found is to resize the image, which is not an option for me.

Edit: There is not only a place it is not working

1.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            profileImage.SetImageURI(uri);
            using (Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data)) //here it throws the exception
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                    byte[] array = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2.

```
using (Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length))
```

Comment: show your code @MadalinSisu

Comment: I think this might help to you. [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)